how can i set parameters to the request function using the revalidateTag function in NEXT.js
i have a fetch function that depends of two parameters, im using On-demand Revalidation next feature:
type GetVideosProps = {
  take: string;
  skip: string;
};

async function getVideos({ take, skip }: GetVideosProps): Promise<Response[]> {
  const url = `${process.env.SERVER_URL}/videos?take=${take}&skip=${skip}`;

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    next: {
      tags: ['videos']
    },
    cache: 'no-cache'
  });

  const data = await response.json();

  return data;
}

im trying to implement infinity scroll and to do it i'll re-fetch this using the revalidateTag() function but my fetch depends of skip and take parameters i must change them before the revalidateTag call. how can i change them or are there i better way to do it.
My Home page
const response = await getVideos({ take: 8, skip: 0 });

